# Add a border icon to the form

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007, titlebar, custom-titlebar

Using Delphi I would like to add another button to the border icon buttons; close, maximize, minimize. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was easy to do prior to Windows Aero. You simply had to listen to the `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_NCACTIVATE` messages to draw on top of the caption bar, and similarly you could use the other `WM_NC*` messages to respond to mouse clicks etc, in particular `WM_NCHITTEST`, `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`, and `WM_NCLBUTTONUP`.

For instance, to draw a string on the title bar, you only had to do

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Msg: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure WMNCActivate(var Msg: TWMNCActivate); message WM_NCACTIVATE;
  private
    procedure DrawOnCaption;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMNCActivate(var Msg: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  inherited;
  DrawOnCaption;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCPaint(var Msg: TWMNCPaint);
begin
  inherited;
  DrawOnCaption;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawOnCaption;
var
  dc: HDC;
begin
  dc := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  try
    TextOut(dc, 20, 2, 'test', 4);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, dc);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Now, this doesn't work with Aero enabled. Still, there is a way to draw on the caption bar; I have done that, but it is far more complicated. See [this article](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/) for a working example.

Answer (score 2):

[Chris Rolliston](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/) wrote a detailed blog about [creating a custom title bar on Vista and Windows 7](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/).

He also wrote a [follow up article](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise/) and posted example code on [CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27688).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set the form's border style property to bsNone and implement your own title bar with all the buttons and custom behaviour you like.